# How to produce emotional speech using ssml prosody element?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, ssml

How to produce emotional speech using ssml prosody element?

I have tried this piece of code to produce sad emotion in the speech, but there are no changes in the voice emotion.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    PromptBuilder pb1 = new PromptBuilder();

    string sad = "<prosody  pitch=\"-20%\" range=\"low\" rate =\"50%\" volume =\"30\"><emphasis level=\"none\">... She  was  sad.  Ellen  cried.  Calvin  said, I  feel  guilty.  Calvin told  Daddy Sam that he broke the lamp.</emphasis></prosody>";

    pb1.AppendSsmlMarkup(sad);
    synth.Speak(pb1);        
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do? Do you get any error messages? Please edit your question with more details to help us answer your question! This page has a lot more info on [Ask] a question that gets good answers

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear.
It works well ,there is no any error; but It doesn't produce the sad emotion in the speech. I need one that used these prosody properties (pitch, rate...etc.) in ssml for producing emotional speech.
Thanks in advance